# Zip list of scalars and lists

Tags: python, list, iteration, tuples

I have a `tuple` that contains both scalars and lists

```
(25.69, [25.5, 29.5], [0.00153, 0.0222], 0.0, [0.04109, 0.08877], [0.31393, 0.34876], [0.75, 0.63])
```

I need to operate on the first `tuple` such that the result is:

```
((25,69, 25.5, 0.00153, 0.0, 0.04109, 0.31393, 0.75), (25.69, 29.5, 0.222, 0.0, 0.08877, 0.34876, 0.63))
```

The first list represents a combination of parameters that need to be passed to functions. I need to convert it to a `tuple` of two `tuples` so each can be passed to the function.

I've looked at `zip`, `map`, and `itertools.izip_longest` but each requires the args to already be split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) with [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions), [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
>>> xs = (25.69, [25.5, 29.5], [0.00153, 0.0222],
....      0.0, [0.04109, 0.08877], [0.31393, 0.34876], [0.75, 0.63])
>>> zip(*(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x, x] for x in xs))  # list(zip(...)) in Py 3
[(25.69, 25.5, 0.00153, 0.0, 0.04109, 0.31393, 0.75),
 (25.69, 29.5, 0.0222, 0.0, 0.08877, 0.34876, 0.63)]
```

The conditional expression was used to convert scalar values to lists.

```
x if isinstance(x, list) else [x, x]
```